# PHP / MySQL - Loading results into an array

Tags: php

I have a SQL query which returns a result of one field, so I have the following:

```
$article_id = $this->item->id;
$authors_default = mysql_query("SELECT multi_authors FROM jos_jxzine_articles WHERE id = '$article_id' LIMIT 1");
$authors_default = mysql_fetch_assoc($authors_default);
echo $authors_default['multi_authors'];
```

This echos out

```
128,129
```

and so on for different queries.

How can I make this into the following

```
array(128,129)
```

To then put into a prewritten function?

Cheers

Comment: To me it looks strange that you are using `$authors_default` for both, the pointer of the result set and the actual data. This might work if you only want to fetch a single value, but I would consider it better practice to assign the return value of `mysql_query` to another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$authors_array = explode(",", $authors_default['multi_authors']);
```

This will break apart your MySQL result into an array.  Since your query pulls a string which is delimited by a comma, the explode() function can be used to separate out the string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 3):

The following code takes that MySQL row and splits it up into pieces using `,` as the delimiter. It then converts that array of strings to an array of integers.

```
$authors_arr = explode(',', $authors_default['multi_authors']);
// $authors_arr = array("128", "129");
$authors_arr = array_map('intval', $authors_arr);
// $authors_arr = array(128, 129);
```

You can then pass that array into a function like so:

```
myFunction($authors_arr); // Or however you have it setup.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is untested since I have removed PHP from my localhost. If I understand you correctly.

```
<?php $arr = explode(',', $authors_default['multi_authors']); print_r($arr); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php